# If we write a statement that is very common, should we use the past tense or present tense or future tense?

Tags: grammar, tense, usage, clauses

If we write a statement that is very common, should we use the past tense or present tense or future tense?

Which one is correct? Or it depends on how old I imagine the reader is?

---

**Examples I came up with:**

The "you" in (1) and (2) are used to refer to an average person (not a specific "you").

> (1) What you **are** interested in at 18 can be different from what you **are** interested in at 40.

> (2) What you **were** interested in at 18 can be different from what you **are** interested in at 40.

> (3) What you **were** interested in at 18 can be different from what you **will be** interested in at 40.

---

**Examples I came up with:**

> (a) What a person **is** interested in at 18 can be different from what that person **is** interested in at 40.

> (b) What a person **was** interested in at 18 can be different from what that person **is** interested in at 40.

> (c) What a person **was** interested in at 18 can be different from what that person **will be** interested in at 40.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which is most appropriate probably depends on your context and readership.  As a general statement, I'd use the present tense versions (1)/(a).

If your readership is around 40, then (2)/(b) identifies more with them.
Likewise if they are 20's/30's then (3)/(c) works.

However, the more you target one group, the more likely to are to alienate other readers.  So a reader in their 60's might read (3)/(c) and then lose interest because it is not relevant to them, but (1)/(a) might keep their attention.